# React Native Use Percentage for Square Image

Tags: react-native

I am using react native, and am trying to create an image which is a fixed percentage of the screen width. However, this image must also be a square. Typically when creating a square image, I would just write this in a style for the image:

```
image: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
  },
```

Which would create an image 200 x 200. I attempted to use percentages like this:

```
image: {
    width: 50%,
    height: 50%,
},
```

However that obviously will scale the image with respect to both the width and height. How can I make the image be a *x* by *x* image where *x* is a percentage of the width of the screen. For example, if the screen is 400px wide, I want a 200 by 200 image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Dimensions to calculate the size of image

```
const _width  = Dimensions.get('screen').width * 0.5
```

then use

```
image: {
    width: _width,
    height: _width,
  },
```